# Haskell - Printing a list of tuples

Tags: list, haskell, tuples

I have a list of tuples in the form:

```
[(String, Int)]
```

How can I print this to display like:

```
String : Int
String : Int
String : Int
...
```

I am very new to Haskell so please make it as clear as possible. Thank you!

Update: Here's how the code of my program now looks:

```
main = do  
    putStrLn "********* Haskell word frequency counter *********"
    putStrLn ""
    conts <- readFile "text.txt"
    let lowConts = map toLower conts
    let counted = countAllWords (lowConts)
    let sorted = sortTuples (counted)
    let reversed = reverse sorted
    putStrLn "Word : Count"
    mapM_ (printTuple) reversed

-- Counts all the words.
countAllWords :: String -> [(String, Int)]
countAllWords fileContents = wordsCount (toWords (noPunc fileContents))

-- Splits words and removes linking words.
toWords :: String -> [String]
toWords s = filter (\w -> w `notElem` ["and","the","for"]) (words s)

-- Remove punctuation from text String.
noPunc :: String -> String
noPunc xs = [ x | x <- xs, not (x `elem` ",.?!-:;\"\'") ]

-- Counts, how often each string in the given list appears.
wordsCount :: [String] -> [(String, Int)]
wordsCount xs = map (\xs -> (head xs, length xs)) . group . sort $ xs

-- Sort list in order of occurrences.
sortTuples :: [(String, Int)] -> [(String, Int)]
sortTuples sort = sortBy (comparing snd) sort


printTuple :: Show a => [(String, a)] -> IO ()
printTuple xs = forM_ xs (putStrLn . formatOne)

formatOne :: Show a => (String, a) -> String
formatOne (s,i) = s ++ " : " ++ show i
```

It returns this error to me:

```
fileToText.hs:18:28:
Couldn't match type ‘(String, Int)’ with ‘[(String, a0)]’
Expected type: [[(String, a0)]]
  Actual type: [(String, Int)]
In the second argument of ‘mapM_’, namely ‘reversed’
In a stmt of a 'do' block: mapM_ (printTuple) reversed
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Try `printTuple :: Show a => [([Char], a)] -> IO ()`. If you print, you _have_ to return an `IO something` type.

Comment: Ah I did not know that, thank you! 

I don't mind how it prints as long as it is in the correct format. I'm very new to Haskell and just trying what I know so far :)

Unfortunately that returns:
Couldn't match type ‘(String, Int)’ with ‘[([Char], a0)]’

Comment: ok - I have to admit I should have called the function `printTuples` (will fix it) - anyway the problem is that you use `mapM_` but you don't really need to (as I already use `forM_`) - so just to `printTuples reversed` instead

Comment: Thank you so much for the help! My program is working fine now :D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

let's start by formatting one item:

```
formatOne :: Show a => (String, a) -> String
formatOne (s,i) = s ++ " : " ++ show i
```

now you can use this function (for example) with `forM_` from `Control.Monad` to print it to the screen like this (`forM_` because we want to *be* in the IO-Monad - because we are going to use `putStrLn`):

```
Prelude> let test = [("X1",4), ("X2",5)]
Prelude> import Control.Monad (forM_)
Prelude Control.Monad> forM_ test (putStrLn . formatOne)
X1 : 4
X2 : 5
```

in a file you would use it like this:

```
import Control.Monad (forM_)

printTuples :: Show a => [(String, a)] -> IO ()
printTuples xs = forM_ xs (putStrLn . formatOne)

formatOne :: Show a => (String, a) -> String
formatOne (s,i) = s ++ " : " ++ show i
```

### compiling file

overall here is a version of your code that will at least compile (cannot test it without the text file ;) )

```
import Control.Monad (forM_)
import Data.Char (toLower)
import Data.List (sort, sortBy, group)
import Data.Ord (comparing)

main :: IO ()
main = do  
    putStrLn "********* Haskell word frequency counter *********"
    putStrLn ""
    conts <- readFile "text.txt"
    let lowConts = map toLower conts
    let counted = countAllWords lowConts
    let sorted = sortTuples counted
    let reversed = reverse sorted
    putStrLn "Word : Count"
    printTuples reversed

-- Counts all the words.
countAllWords :: String -> [(String, Int)]
countAllWords = wordsCount . toWords . noPunc

-- Splits words and removes linking words.
toWords :: String -> [String]
toWords = filter (\w -> w `notElem` ["and","the","for"]) . words

-- Remove punctuation from text String.
noPunc :: String -> String
noPunc xs = [ x | x <- xs, x `notElem` ",.?!-:;\"\'" ]

-- Counts, how often each string in the given list appears.
wordsCount :: [String] -> [(String, Int)]
wordsCount = map (\xs -> (head xs, length xs)) . group . sort

-- Sort list in order of occurrences.
sortTuples :: [(String, Int)] -> [(String, Int)]
sortTuples = sortBy $ comparing snd

-- print one tuple per line separated by " : "
printTuples :: Show a => [(String, a)] -> IO ()
printTuples = mapM_ (putStrLn . formatTuple)
  where formatTuple (s,i) = s ++ " : " ++ show i
```

I also removed the compiler warnings and HLINTed it (but skipped the `Control.Arrow` stuff - I don't think `head &&& length` is more readable option here)

Comment: Thanks for the help! However I've added your code into my program:

Comment: It gives me these errors:

    Couldn't match type ‘[]’ with ‘IO’
    Expected type: [([Char], a0)] -> IO ()
      Actual type: [([Char], a0)] -> [()]

    Couldn't match type ‘(String, Int)’ with ‘[([Char], a0)]’
    Expected type: [[([Char], a0)]]
      Actual type: [(String, Int)]

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: @AlastairWarren please edit your own question - not my answer ;)

Comment: my fault sorry - I messed up the types and pasted the wrong one :( ... should be fixed now

Comment: It now is partly fixed :) However I still get one error:

fileToText.hs:18:28:
    Couldn't match type ‘(String, Int)’ with ‘[(String, a0)]’
    Expected type: [[(String, a0)]]
      Actual type: [(String, Int)]
    In the second argument of ‘mapM_’, namely ‘reversed’
    In a stmt of a 'do' block: mapM_ (printTuple) reversed